# Android. GestureDetector longPress - longer threshold or timeout

Tags: android, gesturedetector, long-click

I need to capture a long press, plus the coordinates of the event.
It seems to me that a longer threshold or timeout for the long press action will fit better.

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        //do something with coordinates
    }
});
this.fl_overlay.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I see in source code of GestureDetector a

```
private static final int LONGPRESS_TIMEOUT =  ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout();
```

Is there a way to extend this value?

Comment: Is it really that hard to create your own long press detector?  Its about 5 lines of code.  Its actually quicker to write than it is to look up whether that setting is changable.